# Creating xml Document In javascript shows error

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to create a `xml document` in `Javascript`. but it will not give required output

Here is my code

```
if(status==0)
        { 


             var objXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlDOM")
             objXML.async = false                
             var objXMLRoot=objXML.createElement("root")
             objXML.documentElement=objXMLRoot 

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("parentname"))
             objXMLRoot.appendChild(0).text=listid

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("childname"))
             objXMLRoot.appendChild(1).text=document.getElementById("childId").value; 

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("childstatus"))
             objXMLRoot.appendChild(2).text=ichildid;                

             AjaxSend(objXMLRoot,'100','1');
        }
```

My problem :  i did't get any data in my xml document . i want to get listid,childid values in my xml document
any help will be appriciated

Comment: @DoctorMick i did't get any data in my xml document . i want to get listid,childid values in my xml document

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read through the "How to ask a good question" page, particularly the section called ["Help others reproduce the problem"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We need to know what your output is and what you're expecting.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Sure i will  look at the documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is some syntax error in your code

try something like below

```
if(status==0)
        { 


             var objXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlDOM")
             objXML.async = false                
             var objXMLRoot=objXML.createElement("root")
             objXML.documentElement=objXMLRoot 

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("parentname"))
             objXMLRoot.childNodes(0).text=listid

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("childname"))
             objXMLRoot.childNodes(1).text=document.getElementById("childId").value; 

             objXMLRoot.appendChild(objXML.createElement("childstatus"))
             objXMLRoot.childNodes(2).text=ichildid;                

             AjaxSend(objXMLRoot,'100','1');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working , i had miss the correct syntax . thanks for helping me